# Getting error : Either JSONWP or W3C capabilities should be provided

Tags: appium-android

Not sure if this is compatibility issue..appium version I am using is 4.0.0 and selenium is 3.0.0

I have checked with latest version of both appium and selenium still getting the same error, below is the error :

[debug] [W3C] Calling AppiumDriver.createSession() with args: [null,null,{"desiredCapabilities":{"appPackage":"com.android.calculator2","appActivity":"com.android.calculator2.Calculator","noReset":"false","automationName":"UiAutomator2","platformVersiob":"9","udid":"emulator-5554","platformName":"Android","deviceName":"Pixel_2_API_28"},"requiredCapabilities":{}}]
[debug] [BaseDriver] Event 'newSessionRequested' logged at 1570772955711 (11:19:15 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time))
[debug] [BaseDriver] Event 'newSessionStarted' logged at 1570772955712 (11:19:15 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time))
[debug] [W3C] Encountered internal error running command: Error: Either JSONWP or W3C capabilities should be provided

Here is the capabilities which I am setting in code :-

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {


    //Set the Capabilities
    System.out.println("Setting Capability");

    DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
    caps.setCapability("deviceName", "Pixel_2_API_28");
    caps.setCapability("udid", "emulator-5554");
    caps.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
    caps.setCapability("platformVersion", "9.0");       
    caps.setCapability("appPackage", "com.android.calculator2");
    caps.setCapability("appActivity", "com.android.calculator2.Calculator");
    caps.setCapability("automationName", "UiAutomator2");
    caps.setCapability("noReset", "false");


    //Instantiate Appium Driver

    System.out.println("Instantiating Driver"); 

    try {

        AndroidDriver<MobileElement> driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), caps);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(80, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        Thread.sleep(10000);

    }catch(MalformedURLException e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());

    }
```